# enable certain commands in root level of a project without writing script nor manual setup for local machine

Tags: bash, command-line, command

Currenly, if I want to run something like `start` in a project, let say `/myproject` I have to make a new bash file and name it like `start` in order to have some sort of command like `./start` to work properly.

But I want to do is somehow I can add some sort of config file into the root folder to run all different kinds of command without `./` needed and simply `start` or anything else as I want to make, without having to create whole bunch of bash files.

Is there a way to setup it so if someone just pull a git repo down can just have it?

Assume that the git repo also contains `package.json` or maybe gradle.

However, I dont want to use `npm run xxx` or `gradle xxx` its just too much typing...

Sorry if I am asking too much for a setup lol

Comment: a security hole, but `export PATH="$PATH:."` (note the `.` as the last entry) someplace at the begining of your project will give you this behavior. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter would you elaborate on `someplace at the begining of your project`? and how its a security hole? Thank you very much!

Comment: You could put the export path, like @shellter pointed out, in your .bashrc.  But it is a security hole since you could replace system commands with your own scripts and get them to be executed by a privileged user.  Ex. you create a script, locally, called `su`.  Then you ask someone to use `su` to do something with root user.  If that user is not careful, he would run your version of `su` instead of `/bin/su`.  I got the root password out of an admin in university using this trick.  But a serious admin would always type /bin/su, to go around that.

Comment: FYI any experienced unix user does not mind typing `./`

Comment: @Nic3500 typing ./ is very ergonomically uncomfortable imo from a experience ish command line user point of view. ha

Comment: Ok, but it shouldn't IMHO.

Comment: yes, we are getting into the realm of opinions. can be controversial  for sure ha